# $2\sin(\pi/6)-1$ is not exactly 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So while doing some basic trig problems, I had a problem with $2\sin(\pi/6)-1$. $2\sin(\pi/6)$ is exactly $1$, but somehow $2\sin(\pi/6)-1$ is $-1.11\times10^{-16}$.

I had previously thought that $\sin(\pi/6)$ is defined to be exactly $0.5$, especially because the ratio of a $30$-$60$-$90$ triangle is exactly $1$-$\sqrt{3}$ - $2$.

So why does this happen? Is $\sin(\pi/6)$ not actually exactly 0.5?

[image]

Comment: Machine roundoff error.

Comment: Thats what I thought too, but just wanted to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: It means that the program you use does not define $\sin\frac\pi6$ but tries to compute it. Observe that there is even no possibility for a computer to store the exact value of $\pi $ in any positional number system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an all too common rounding error. This claimed nonzero value is $-2^{-53}$, a common small negative value for a [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) due to $2^{-53}$ being the smallest possible nonzero significand error.

Answer (score 0):

We can show that: $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

in fact, consider a right triangle with side lenght $l$, and draw the perpendicular line to the base. Let  $H$ the foor of the perpendicular. The triangle $ABH$ is a right  triangle, so we have:
$$\overline{AH}=\frac{l}{2} \land \overline{AB}=l$$
This demonstrates that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$. Your error is an approximation error and in fact you have a result $1\cdot10^{-16}$ which is very small.